# Invoking-command in powershell 2012 (remotely) for ArcPy errors but local cmd or python shell work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-server, error-000732, powershell

I've written a data update script that works really well, it deletes a target feature class and uses the feature class to feature class geoprocessing tool to copy data from SQL 2012 into it's predecessors location.

The ***script works when run via python shell or scheduled via cmd***. However our preferred workflow tool uses ***powershell 2012*** (remotely). Invoking-command in powershell for our ArcPy script ***errors*** in several places.My main concern is the feature class to feature class tool:

> *ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset \bacon.sde\tasty_Prod.dbo\v_cheese does not exist or is not supported
>   Failed to execute (FeatureClassToFeatureClass).*

Why would the feature class to feature class tool work via python shell and cmd and not via powershell?

[image: PowerShell Example]

The same script uses table to table (updating tables) and it works in powershell.. only things that have geometry have issues..

Comment: This might be better addressed on StackOverflow, it doesn't sound like an arcpy problem.. Be sure the database connection files exist for the user credentials that's executing the power shell remotely, it might be a missing connection file or a permission problem.

Comment: Is your connection to the database using Windows authentication?

Answer (score 1):

This is a double hop problem. In other words, a client machine is executing a script from a remote server. Received guidance on this from the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18113651/powershell-remoting-policy-does-not-allow-the-delegation-of-user-credentials).

The following command should be executed on the remote server:

```
Enable-PSRemoting

Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Server
```

The following commands should be executed on the local client:

```
Enable-PSRemoting
set-item wsman:localhost\client\trustedhosts -value *
Enable-WSManCredSSP -Role Client –DelegateComputer *
```

Use gpedit.msc to enable Delegating Fresh Credentials to WSMAN/*:

---

1. Expand Local Computer Policy, expand Computer Configuration, expand Administrative Templates, expand System, and then click Credential Delegation.
2. In the Settings pane, double-click Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication.
3. In the Allow Delegating Fresh Credentials with NTLM-only Server Authentication dialog box, do the following:

   - Click Enabled.
   - In the Options area, click Show.
   - In Value, type WSMAN/* and then click OK. Make sure that *concatenate OS defaults with input above* is selected, and then click OK.

After setting up Secure Service Provider credentials, in order to use this within an automated job a credential object will need to be created. 
Follow the instructions in this post to learn how to do that: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/koteshb/2010/02/12/powershell-how-to-create-a-pscredential-object/

Your command should be constructed like this:

```
icm -ComputerName $dev_app_svr -FilePath "$gisdb\Weekly\Weekly_DBTasks_1.0.ps1" -Authentication CredSSP -Credential $svrcreds
```

The powershell script Weekly_DBTasks_1.0.ps1 will then reference your python script.